# WCF Data services remove milliseconds from DateTime when expand

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I get some strange behavior, when using WCF Data Services 5.6.
In my case, I have table, with 1 column set with Concurrency=Fixed, and this column hold date time field from database, updated each time when row is edited.
In case I just retrieve entity - this column has correct value with milliseconds. But if I do mapping - milliseconds are removed.

Here is a issue at glance :

====================================================================

```
void Main()
{
    var b = from p in TABLE1 where p.ID == 100 select p;
    b.Dump();
}
```

Request in this case is : http://xxxx/Data.svc/TABLE1(100M)
And data returned from service is :

```
<d:COL1 m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-02-16T12:13:52.972</d:COL1>
```

====================================================================

As you can see , here time is returned with milliseconds - .972
In other case :

```
void Main()
{

    var tmp = from p in TABLE1 where p.ID == 100 select 
    new TABLE1() 
    {
        ID=p.ID,
        COL1=p.COL1
    };
    var a1 = tmp.ToList();
    a1.Dump();
}
```

Request in this case is : http://xxxx/Data.svc/TABLE1(100M)?$select=ID,COL1

```
  <d:COL1 m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-02-16T12:13:52</d:COL1>
```

====================================================================

Time is returned without milliseconds.

Does anybody have same problem? May be its a bug in the WCF Data services or in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like I found an answer to this, or at least way to avoid the problem.
First I traced generated SQL from framework, and I see that in first case, im getting SQL

```
 SELECT ID, COL1 FROM TABLE1
```

and in second case, I got

```
 SELECT ID, CAST( COL1 AS DATETIME) FROM TABLE1
```

which cause the problem.

Then I tried to update EF to version 6, WCF Data services to version 5.6.3, 
Oracle ODP to latest one, tried to use Oracle managed driver... no any success.

Then I played little bit with table definition, and I saw that my col1 with type TIMESTAMP in database and DateTime in the model was defined as NOT NULL.
If I remove this from database definition, I got right value with milliseconds.

So , may be this is a bug in Oracle driver, but probably this is a bug in the WCF Data Services. At least I found a way to use concurrency in my case with this solution.